# "There's no.... " and " it's no .... "

Tags: meaning

Is there any differnce in meanings between the following pair of sentences?

1) a. There's no denying the fact.
   b. It's no denying the fact.

2) a. There's no point denying the fact.
   b. It's no point denying the fact.

Answer (score 1):

'There's no denying the fact' and 'There's no point denying the fact' are both perfectly correct English idioms, as in:

'There's no (point) denying the fact that what has just happened in the Philippines is a natural disaster of the first magnitude.'

'It is no (point) denying the fact' is what a lot of people say, but it is incorrect English. It probably arises from people mishearing the previous construction, and then from others copying them.  In a similar way some people say 'I would of gone', when they should say 'I would have gone'